# How does shell preserve command file input line boundary?

Tags: bash, shell, io, posix, posix-api

The description of STDIN of sh in [SUSv4 2016](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) edition says

> It shall not read ahead in such a manner that any characters intended to be read by the invoked command are consumed by the shell

I did an experiment to see it in action, by redirecting the following script file into `sh -s`:

```
#!/bin/sh
./rewind # a c program that reads up its stdin, prints it to stdout, before SEEK_SET its standard input to 0. 
echo 1234-1234
```

And it keeps printing out "echo 1234-1234". (Had shell consumed whole block of file, it would only print out "1234-1234")

So obviously, shells (at least my ones) do read at line boundaries.

But however, when I examined the FreeBSD ash "input.c" source codes, it reads in BUFSIZ-byte blocks, and I don't understand how it preserves line boundaries.

What I want to know is: How does shells preserve line boundaries when their source codes apparently shows that they read in blocks?

Comment: Interesting topic area, but I'm afraid I don't understand what the actual question is. Can you be more specific? How have you proven to your own satisfaction that the different shells read "command input files" in blocks? Which behaviour did you see, and what did you expect to see? Can you link to the page in SUSv4? How do we get a hold of `rewind`?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong read.  When the shell reads input for the purpose of executing that input as commands, it is not relevant to the rule you are asking about.  When the shell invokes the `read` command to read from its input, it will typically read in blocks of size 1.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I suppose. That's the only possible portable way to do it. When I saw FreeBSD ash just read in BUFSIZ blocks, I was shocked and thought there can't have been an ioctl or fcntl command to configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I compiled the FreeBSD ash with NO_HISTORY macro defined to 1 in "shell.h", it consumes the whole file and outputs only 1234-1234 on my rewind testing program. Apparently, the FreeBSD `ash` relies on libedit to preserve IO line boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Standard input isn't seekable in some cases, for example if it is redirected from a pipe or from a terminal. E.g. having a file called `rew` with a content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 123
perl -E 'seek(STDIN,0,0) or die "$!"' #the rewind
```

and using it as

```
bash -s < rew
```

prints

```
123
123
...
123
^C
```

so, when the STDIN is *seekable* it will work as expected, but trying the same from a pipe, such:

```
cat rew | bash -s   #the cat is intentional here :)
```

will print

```
123
Illegal seek at -e line 1.
```

So, your c-program `rewind` should print an error, when it is trying to seek in un-seekable input.

Answer (score 0):

You can demonstrate this (surprising) behaviour with the following script:

```
$ cat test.sh
cut -f 1
printf '%s\t%s\n' script file
```

If you pass it to standard input of your shell, line 2 onward should become the standard input of the `cut` command:

```
$ sh < test.sh
printf '%s\t%s\n' script file
```

If you instead run it normally and input literally <kbd>foo</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>bar</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd>, you should instead see standard input being linked as normal:

```
$ sh test.sh 
foo     bar
foo
script  file
```

Annotated:

```
$ sh test.sh # Your command
foo     bar # Your input to `cut`
foo # The output of `cut`
script  file # The output of `printf`
```